# MongoDB with Spring Data - Check if Criteria is empty

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using MongoDB with Spring Data.

I want to check if a Criteria (in package org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query) is empty, this is, if it was created like this:

```
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
```

Is there any flag to check this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I have found is:

```
public static boolean isTrivial(Criteria criteria){
    return criteria.equals(new Criteria());
}
```